# Power BI Workspace name from report GUID

Tags: powershell, powerbi, admin

I have a report GUID for one report & I want to find out the workspace it originated from. I am using Powershell & from their using Get-PowerBIReport cmdlet & I am able to get certain information like dataset id, embed url but not anything specific to workspace. Does anybody have any idea on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the workspaces, and then get all the Datasets in each one.  eg

```
foreach ($ws in Get-PowerBIGroup -All)
{
    foreach ($ds in get-powerbidataset -Workspace $ws  )
    {
        write-host "Workspace $($ws.Id), Dataset $($ds.Id)"
    }
}
```